# If my protonmail password is compromised, does that potentially mean that my whole account is, permanently?

Tags: encryption, passwords, email, password-cracking, protonmail

My (limited) understanding is that my password is used to encrypt the keys which are used to encrypt my mail messages on protonmail's servers. Does that mean that knowledge of my password could potentially let an adversary find out what the keys associated to my account are, and thus render password change useless? Or are keys periodically subject to change as well, and all my emails re-encrypted? Or have I got it completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No.

According to the [ProtonMail Team](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProtonMail/comments/971p6w/why_doesnt_protonmail_use_forward_secrecy/), ProtonMail uses perfect forward secrecy:

> We use PFS in our TLS cipher suites for both web access and SMTP, and have since the beginning

This means, that if correctly implemented, it gives assurances that session keys will not be compromised even if the private key of the server is compromised.

It protects past sessions against future compromises of secret keys or passwords.